# Form options as radio buttons or regular buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm very new to Rails, doing a few tutorials, and I don't have a background in web development, so apologies in advance.

I'm creating a pretty simple app that allows a user to select one of three available status updates. Should I store these three status updates as a string or integer? Currently, my Postgres database stores the statuses as integers, though I'm also curious if there's a way I can specify that only the numbers 1, 2, or 3 can be inserted.

Second question: I want to display a form that shows as three buttons, each button corresponding to a specific, set status update. I want the button to display with a string inside so that it's human readable, but with that status update corresponding to either 1, 2, or 3. The user can choose which status, change which status they've selected if they change their mind before submitting, and then hit a submit button once they've made up their mind.

Should I use radio buttons to accomplish this? If so, how should I make it where the radio button displays text and then saves as the integer? Or should I just use a normal button?

Many thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Bot, I was able to create a hash defining human readable values to the corresponding status integers like so:

config/application.rb:

```
module MyAppName
   class Application < Rails::Application

   INDENT_STATUSES = {1 => "DUE", 2 => "SHIPPING", 3 => "SHIPPED", 4 => "CLOSED"}.freeze 
   end
end
```

And _form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@status) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :status , :as => :radio_buttons ,:collection => MyAppName::Application::INDENT_STATUSES.keys, :label_method => lambda { |k| MyAppName::Application::INDENT_STATUSES[k]}, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', :include_blank => false %> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

However in index.html.erb, the status displays as the number rather than the human readable version:

```
<h1>Listing statuses</h1>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Status</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= status.status %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', status %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_path(status) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', status, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Status', new_status_path %>
```

How do I get `status.status` to show the human readable value of the hash I created?

I used scaffolding to build my statuses, so the status controller is what you'd expect.

Comment: Please put code you have tried here, so that your question can be answered accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have key value pair based fields in a rails app, you need to first define a hash containing those pairs. If it's going to be constant across the application you can use config/application.rb file to define it.

```
module MyAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
     INDENT_STATUSES = {1 => "DUE", 2 => "SHIPPING", 3 => "SHIPPED", 4 => "CLOSED"}.freeze 
  end
end
```

Then in your form you can do something like this if you are using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

```
    <%= f.input :status , :as => :radio_buttons ,:collection => MyAppName::Application::INDENT_STATUSES.keys, :label_method => lambda { |k| MyAppName::Application::INDENT_STATUSES[k]}, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', :include_blank => false %>
```

And don't forget to restart the server after adding anything in application.rb file.
Hope it helps.

**Update**

Now to display the status in show pages you need to simply get the value corresponding to status key from hash.

```
 MyAppName::Application::INDENT_STATUSES[indent.status.to_i]
```

You can use it directly in view.

```
<td><%= MyAppName::Application::INDENT_STATUSES[status.status.to_i] %></td>
```

Or you can define a method in Model.

```
class Status

  #
  # 
  def status_label
    MyAppName::Application::INDENT_STATUSES[self.status.to_i]
  end
end
```

and in view use it like this.

```
<td><%= status.status_label %></td>
```

Comment: Nice, @Bot, that did work! It'd have taken me a while to figure that out. How would I then display the human readable form of the status on the index page that lists my statuses? 'status.status' just displays the number - how can I point it to the hash I defined?